# How to disable unused variable warning for a struct field

Tags: rust

```rust
pub struct A {
    a : u64,
    b : bool,
}

pub fn foo() -> u64 {
    let aa = A {
        a: 10,
        b: false
    };
    return aa.a;
}
```

```
warning: field `b` is never read
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
1 | pub struct A {
  |            - field in this struct
2 |     a : u64,
3 |     b : bool,
  |     ^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default
```

I only want to disable warning for `b` and not the full struct such that any subsequent addition of member variable to `struct A` continues to be checked for unused variable.

Comment: Would calling the field `_b` be an option to consider? It suppresses the warnings AFAIK

Comment: Actually nevermind, `#[allow(dead_code)] b : bool,` works in field definition too

Comment: `#[allow(dead_code)] b : bool` works! if you put that as answer i'll accept it. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just put `#[allow(dead_code)]` in front of field's definition.

```
pub struct A {
    a : u64,
    #[allow(dead_code)]
    b : bool,
}
```

Comment: Might be useful to add that for every warning the compiler will add a ``note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default`` from which you can derive the necessary `#[allow(…)]`